# Ultra slow BIOS boot on Samsung NP530 notebook PC

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I purchased a Samsung laptop model NP530U4C from Amazon in December 2012 and just two days ago it has suddenly developed a slow BIOS boot.

The laptop has a Phoenix BIOS.

I have made NO hardware changes and have Fast Boot enabled.  The laptop previously took 20 seconds to boot into Windows, but now it takes nearly 10 minutes for the Windows boot process to start.  At the end of the BIOS boot process a blue bar appears across the bottom of the screen (next to the Phoenix logo) before Windows starts booting up.

On a couple of separate occasions, when Windows installed I was greeted by a message telling me that Windows is installing device drives for the CD/DVD drive as well as the SanDisk i100 SSD 24gb cache drive.

When I manage to press F2, after waiting nearly 2 minutes for the key press to register the BIOS navigation is painfully slow taking nearly 20-30 seconds to register the key presses.

I have taken the hard drive out to see if this speeds up the BIOS boot, just in case the hard drive is failing, but the problem still persists.  I even installed CrystalDiskInfo and it reported the drive health is good with an operating temperature of 36C.

I have filled out a support request to Samsung so I don't know how long I'll be waiting for an answer.

This all seem to have started after I plugged a laptop cooling board into the USB port.

I am wondering whether the USB laptop cooler has somehow shorted out the USB port, or has done some damage to the motherboard.

Also, to turn on the laptop I used to have to hold the power key down for 1 second, but now I just need to tap it for a fraction of a second for it to power up.  I am not sure what this means.

Has anyone got any ideas to explain why my laptop developed this sudden problem?

Comment: A bad battery or a bad CD/DVD drive can cause this.